# How I display a context menu only for the column headers in a Silverlight DataGrid?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, datagrid

In a Silverlight DataGrid I'd like to display a context menu just when the user right clicks on one of the column headers, or elsewhere in the column header row. How do I do this?

Comment: You'll need to be targeting Silverlight 5 to be able to do this.

Comment: @ChrisF Why's that? Silverlight 4 supports context menus, doesn't it?

Comment: Context menu handling in SL5 is much easier.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Behavior that will do this for you:

```
public class ColumnHeaderContextMenu : Behavior<DataGrid>
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ContextMenuProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ContextMenu", typeof (ContextMenu), typeof (ColumnHeaderContextMenu), new PropertyMetadata(default(ContextMenu)));

    public ContextMenu ContextMenu
    {
        get { return (ContextMenu) GetValue(ContextMenuProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ContextMenuProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();

        AssociatedObject.Loaded += HandleLoaded;
        AssociatedObject.Unloaded += HandleUnloaded;
    }

    private void HandleUnloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ContextMenu != null)
        {
            ContextMenu.Owner = null;
        }
    }

    private void HandleLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var columnHeadersPresenter = AssociatedObject.GetVisualDescendants().OfType<DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter>().FirstOrDefault();

        if (ContextMenu != null)
        {
            ContextMenu.Owner = columnHeadersPresenter;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();

        AssociatedObject.Loaded -= HandleLoaded;
        AssociatedObject.Unloaded -= HandleUnloaded;
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
<sdk:DataGrid>
 <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <Behaviors:ColumnHeaderContextMenu>
        <Behaviors:ColumnHeaderContextMenu.ContextMenu>
            <Controls:ContextMenu>
                <Controls:MenuItem Header="Choose Columns" Command="{Binding EditColumns}"/>
            </Controls:ContextMenu>
        </Behaviors:ColumnHeaderContextMenu.ContextMenu>
    </Behaviors:ColumnHeaderContextMenu>
 </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</sdk:DataGrid>
```